# Meaning of 表現する in an article about programming

Tags: meaning

The original sentence is

> NamesファイルのLast_name配列の１要素分をAttributesクラス**で表現します**。

Normally, 表現する is translated as "express" but since we don't say "**express** one element of the Last_name array **with** the Attributes class" what else could it mean?

Classes are used to represent information, so I thought it might be "represent" but various permutations with that word have not yielded any results either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see no reason not to use "represent".

> NamesファイルのLast_name配列の１要素分をAttributesクラスで表現します。
>
> [We] represent one element of the `Last_names` array in the `Names` file using the `Attributes` class.

Which can be rephrased to:

> The `Attributes` class is used to represent one element of the `Last_names` array in the `Names` file.

Comment: やっぱりそうですね！The client (and translator, actually) were insisting it should be express... Thank you!